# JQuery DatePicker and beforeShowDay

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am desperately trying to use this feature to enable only specific days in my datepicker, but the `beforeShowDay` function is never triggered :(

even this is not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*initialisation des composants*/
    initComponent();
});


availableDates = new Array();

/* Fonction d'initialisation des composants */
function initComponent(){
    /* Date retrait */
    $("#dateRetrait").datepicker();

    $("#dateRetrait").datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        console.log("bsd");
        alert("bsd");
    }});

    //$("#dateRetrait").datepicker({buttonImage: "../../../Images/boutons/btn_calendier.png"});
    //$("#dateRetrait").datepicker({showButtonPanel: true });
    //$("#dateRetrait").datepicker({beforeShow: function() {setTimeout(function() {$(".ui-datepicker").css("z-index", 9999999999);}, 10);}});

    $('#comboLieux').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#comboCreneau').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#dateRetrait').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#dateRetrait').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date());

    $("#dateRetrait").datepicker("option","dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy');
}
```

If you have any ideas, I would greatly appreciate it!

in fact, even this is not working:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(d) {
          console.log(d);
          alert(d);
        }});
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <div class="div-date-retrait">
<input type="text" id="dateRetrait" name="dateRetrait"/>
</div>

Comment: Also what does the rest of your js look like, in particular, the section where you call function: `initComponent()`?

Comment: I',ve just added the code in the question

Comment: Finally, what dates do you want to enable?

Comment: in fact I have an array with allowed dates and this code: $("#dateRetrait").datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(d)
           {
            var dmy =  (d.getMonth()+1);
        if(d.getMonth()<9) dmy="0"+dmy;
        dmy+= "-";
        if(d.getDate()<10) dmy+="0";
        dmy+=d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear();
      
      console.log(dmy+' : '+($.inArray(dmy, availableDates)));
      if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
       return [true, "","Available"];
      }

               return [false,"","unAvailable"];
           }})    
but even with only an alert it's not called  :(

Comment: if I remove the minDate from my second exemple, it's working...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to [jQueryUI's Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) API,

[image]

This explains why

```
$("#dateRetrait").datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        console.log("bsd");
        alert("bsd");
    }});
```

does not work.

Also I noticed you are calling `.datepicker()` multiple times and each time you are giving it different parameters.

Instead of:

```
$("#dateRetrait").datepicker();

$("#dateRetrait").datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        console.log("bsd");
        alert("bsd");
    }});

$('#dateRetrait').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date());

$("#dateRetrait").datepicker("option","dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy');
```

Try doing this:

```
$("#dateRetrait").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: new Date(), 
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        var dmy = (d.getMonth()+1); 
        if(d.getMonth()<9) 
            dmy="0"+dmy; 
        dmy+= "-"; 

        if(d.getDate()<10) dmy+="0"; 
            dmy+=d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear(); 

        console.log(dmy+' : '+($.inArray(dmy, availableDates)));

        if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
            return [true, "","Available"]; 
        } else{
             return [false,"","unAvailable"]; 
        }
    }
    });
```

I have also provided you with a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yTMwu/18/ .  Hope this helps!

Comment: you are my god!!!!
I didn't think the multiple calls could annoy the component...

Thank so much!!!

Comment: Haha no problem.  Just make sure to call `.datepicker()` once in the future. happy coding!

Comment: Does this break if you have multiple ids that use that datepicker()?

Answer (score 5):

Dom gave good explain. And I would like to add more shorten code:

If you have array of **availableDates** in format: 0000-00-00 (yyyy-mm-dd)

```
var availableDates = ["2020-01-05", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-14"];

$("#dateRetrait").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: new Date(), 
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {        
        var year = d.getFullYear(),
            month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
            day = ("0" + (d.getDate())).slice(-2);

        var formatted = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

        if ($.inArray(formatted, availableDates) != -1) {
            return [true, "","Available"]; 
        } else{
            return [false,"","unAvailable"]; 
        }
    }
});
```

**beforeShowDay** - works each time, before render day))

**$.inArray** - find value in array (-1 if no value)

In this solution, you can make **stopDates**, just change line:

```
if ($.inArray(formatted, availableDates) != -1) {
```

to

```
if ($.inArray(formatted, availableDates) == -1) {
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 3):

The date being passed into the callback function is a full-fledged date-and-time.  So if you want it to be compared against a short date string, one of them must be converted.  This snippet of just the beforeShowDay attribute portion of the datepicker demonstrates that a conversion is necessary.  Here I simply disable a single date on the calendar to prove the point.

```
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var dd = date.getDate();
                var mm = date.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
                var shortDate = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
                var test = "12/30/2014";
                if (shortDate == test) {
                    return [false, "" ];
                } else {
                    return [true, "" ];
                }
            }
```