# Disable days jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to be able to disable some bank holidays which take place every year for example Christmas but I also want to be able to disable days which only happen one year

This is my code I have already

```
  var unavailableDates = ["25-12", "26-12", "1-1"];

    function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1);
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }


    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
        var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        return noWeekend[0] ? unavailable(date) : noWeekend;
    }
```

Any body know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call like this :

```
$(".selector").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays})
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay the api of jQuery UI Datepicker

```
beforeShowDay    Type: Function( Date date )

Default: null
A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
[0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
[1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default presentation
[2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.
```

[JQuery DatePicker and beforeShowDay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484159/jquery-datepicker-and-beforeshowday)

and this may help