# Date Picker Options not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I tried every options. MaxDate, MinDate,  Beforeshowday. But its still not working. But my Datepicker is showing and working well. But I cant configure any options in my date picker. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    minDate: '0',
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout the code sample from https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Dates in other months</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
          showOtherMonths: true,
          selectOtherMonths: true
        });
      });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And for beforeShowDay, Please check [JQuery DatePicker and beforeShowDay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484159/jquery-datepicker-and-beforeshowday)

Comment: This helped Thank you!. My error was I duplicated the .datepicker functions and it messed up the jquery program.

Comment: @JonBonJoviMateo Glad I could help.