# datepicker: Prevent days past a certain day from being selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

We're using jQuery UI datepicker and need to limit the selection so the user can't select days past 28 for any month... not seeing this as an option or quite how to inject this, but I'd be fine also just writing my own Javascript after the fact to change the day if they select one we don't want.

Tried function beforeShowDay

```
jQuery("input[nodeName='date']").datepicker('option', {beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    if(d == 29 || d == 30 || d == 31) {
        return [false];
    } else return [true];
}});
```

and it works however it also closes the calendar as soon as it opens for some reason.

We're using jQuery UI 1.10 datepicker and there's no feasible way we can upgrade with our decrepit app.

Comment: on select date event: if day > 28 show error and day = 1

Comment: also show what you have tried

Comment: @bassxzero What do you mean exactly "on select date event"... is that a certain function you're aware of? I'm trying to avoid modifying the datepicker code (jQuery UI 1.10).

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484159/jquery-datepicker-and-beforeshowday