# django : How to disable dates in datepicker, based on the entries form db?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I have n number of dates defined in this below model in the database, these are directly inserted by admin, not by modelforms or anything.

```
class Calendar(models.Model):

    date = models.DateField()
    occasion = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

the form that has the date fields,

```
class LeaveRequestForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = (... "from_date", "to_date" ...)
        model = Leave

        widgets =  {
            ...
            'from_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
            'to_date' : DateInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}),
            ...

        }
```

I have this datepicker script which disable weekends,

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker(
          {
            minDate : 0,
            beforeShowDay : $.datepicker.noWeekends
          }
        );
    });

    </script>
```

Now I want to disable the dates defined in the database + weekends as well. How do I do that?

update :

```
var array = {{ 
               {% for x in disabled_dates %}
               {{x.dates}}
               {% endfor  %} 
            }}

$('datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return array.indexOf(string) != -1 ? [false] : $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    }
});
```

No luck yet!

Comment: The answers here were helpful to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484159/jquery-datepicker-and-beforeshowday

Comment: @devdob okay but why did you comment ?

Comment: What do you mean? What should I do instead?

Comment: It shows how to disable dates, isnt that what you are asking about?!

Comment: @devdob `Now I want to disable the dates defined in the database + weekends as well. How do I do that?`

Answer (score 2):

As referenced from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400775/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-array-of-dates) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484159/jquery-datepicker-and-beforeshowday),

```
var array = [
    {% for x in disabled_dates %}
        {{x.dates}}
    {% endfor  %} 
]

$('datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return array.indexOf(string) != -1 ? [false] : $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    }
});
```

Edit: Added the weekends alongside your array of dates.

Edit: Added for loop for dates (although i think you should've sent a ready list from your view function)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: yup, but no luck yet!

Comment: What problem are you still facing?

Comment: The for loop to retrieve data from db

Comment: Check the answer now, this should solve you problem hopefully.